# Delete only directories in maven

Tags: regex, maven

I am Using maven to create a war file

my folder `<app>` contains `folder1  folder2 file1 ..`

i want to get only file1

I have tried with the following..

```
 <packagingExcludes>app/*/*.js</packagingExcludes>
```

any help here

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is correct but the regex looks different.We use  ** to indicate multiple directories and * to indicate an optional part of a file or directory name, as mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html). If I am not wrong, your regex looks like excluding all .js files in all folders of app, which is different from your requirement

Comment: thanks for your reply ramzy ... but i want to detect file name and folder name using regex so that i can mention in  packagingExcludes

Comment: In the post, it clearly mentions the following         <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>. So you can use **<packagingExcludes>folder1/file1.txt,folder2/file2.jsp,folder3/folder3.1</packagingExcludes>**. The above excludes file1.txt in folder1 directory, file2.jsp in folder2 directory and folder3.1 directory inside folder3 directory

Comment: but there are many files ... i cannot follow this approach ... i need to use a regex expression

Comment: yes for regex, you have to identify the pattern. I hope you have seen this line "You can use wildcards such as ** to indicate multiple directories and * to indicate an optional part of a file or directory nam" in the link provided above